# Elasicsearch- Indexing documents based on change of sequence of characters

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a set of documents that has to be indexed in the following way:

```
1. fs$#56s as fs,$#,56,s
2. FSand-hgfh as fsand,-,hgfh
```

Is there a way to do so? 
Thank you!

Comment: You can do that with pattern replace token filters but if there are more than these two patterns then you are going to be wiring up a bunch of those

Comment: Look at the delimiter token filter. In combination with a custom type table this could be possible